# FuelPHP での、 Controller に定義したクラスの読み込み

Tags: php, テスト, fuelphp

現在以下の様なファイルを作成しています。

*[fuel/app/modules/hoge/classes/controller/hoge.php]*

```php
namespace Hoge
{
class Controller_Hoge extends \Controller
{
  public function aaa(){}
}

class Hoge_Util
{
  public static function bbb(){}
}
}
```

こちらに対してテストを書こうと思い、以下の様なテストを作成しました。

*[fuel/app/modules/hoge/tests/testhogeutil.php]*

```php
class Test_Hoge_Util
{
  public function test_bbb()
  {
    \Module::load('Hoge');
    $bbb = Hoge_Util::bbb();
    $this->assertEquals(1,$bbb);
  }
}
```

`php oil test` を実行したところ、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
Fatal Error - Class 'Hoge\Hoge_Util' not found
```

おそらく `hoge.php` の `Hoge_Util` がロードできていないことが原因ではないかと思うのですが、
FuelPHP では、このように一つのファイルに複数のクラスが存在する場合は、最初に書いてあるクラスしかロードされないのでしょうか？もしくは、 Controller ディレクトリにあるので、クラス名に `Controller` の文字列を入れないといけないのでしょうか？

ご存知のかたいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけると助かります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FuelPHPに限りませんが、ほとんどのPHPでのオートローダはクラス名からファイルを探すので、
Hoge\Hoge_Utilクラスがあれば、それに対応したファイル名のファイルを探し、そのファイル
をロードします。しかし、このケースではそういうファイルは存在しないのでオートロードでき
ません。

1ファイル1クラスにするのが通常です。

FuelPHPでのコントローラの名前空間の指定方法は、以下の公式ドキュメントの翻訳にあります。

http://fuelphp.jp/docs/1.8/general/modules.html#/module_namespace

デフォルト設定であれば、モジュール名の名前空間に `Controller_クラス名` という
命名規則になりますので、現状でよいように思います。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
なるほど、オートローダの仕組み、理解しました。
ファイルからではなく、クラス名からファイルを探すものなんですね。
やはり1ファイル1クラスにしておくのが妥当というか正しい形なんでしょうね。。